# Element not visible error with XPath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I got the problem with an XPath.

I can use this xpath: `//*[@id='name']//*[@class='class']//div[1]` -> can run ok.

But I want use div[2] ex: `//*[@id='name']//*[@class='class']//div[2]` , it gives error that **element is not visible.**
Anyone help me plz, I don't know why div[1] can run but div[2] is not **visible**.

My HTML **code** here:

```
<div class="class">
      <div class="action-item" data-id="24" data-actioncode="STT">
             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
                                S T T
      </div>
      <div class="action-item" data-id="29" data-actioncode="FULL">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
                                FULL
      </div>
      <div class="action-item" data-id="30" data-actioncode="TEACHER">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
                               TEACHER
      </div>
</div>
```

Code I have tried:

```
WebElement btnElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='name']//[@class='class']//div[2]"));  
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,10 ); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(btnElement)); 
btnElement.click();
```

Comment: can get STT xpath but FULL xpath can't run. Code i use:   WebElement btnElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id="name"]//[@class='class']//div[2]"));

        WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,10 );
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(btnElement));
        btnElement.click();

Comment: I guess the xpath `//[@id='name']//[@class='class']//div[2]` can match more than one elements on page,  but the first one in matched list is not visible, and it's not the one you want.  You can manually try the xpath to confirm my guess.

Comment: Problem with xpath, your xpath matches one or more elements, please do double check around duplicate xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector path as well like for div 2 it is :

```
div.action-item:nth-child(2)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this **code** :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-actioncode='FULL']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-actioncode='FULL']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to click on the element with text as **FULL** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable and you can use either of the following locators :

- `css_selector` (attribute based) :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.class div.action-item[data-actioncode='FULL']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath` (attribute based) :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='class']//div[@class='action-item' and @data-actioncode='FULL']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath` (text based) :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='class']//div[@class='action-item'][normalize-space()='FULL']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the action-item class to validate.

use x-path to identify the classname and then do an n-th child:

```
xpath("//[@id='name']//[@class='class']//[@class='action-item']:nth-child(2)"));
```

or you can use the index value as well, as these are inside the same class.
difference is, the index value for the second item is gonna be 1.

alternately, you can use cssContainText as well to identify by the text.